# numpy where command on arrays with dtype=object

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to understand the following:

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([np.array([0, 2, 3]), np.array([0, 2, 3]), np.array([4, 4]), 4], dtype=object)
np.where(foo == 4)
```

returns an empty list `(array([], dtype=int64),)`.  But I can clearly see that the 4th element is 4:

```
foo[3] == 4
True
```

So how can I find the indices for elements in foo that equal some value without having to loop through it?

Comment: odd... the `==` comparison doesn't seem to be broadcasting.

Comment: I'm not sure why `foo == 4` is returning `False` rather than returning an object array or complaining about the truth values of arrays with more than one element.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what's going on:

When you use a comparison operator on a NumPy array, it returns an array of booleans with the same shape as the input array. Each value is the result of `bool(x[i] == 4)`

if you have a list, you get

```py
>>> bool([4, 4, 4] == 4)
False
```

with a numpy array, you get:

```py
>>> bool(np.array([4, 4, 4]) == 4)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-65795746028a> in <module>()
----> 1 bool(np.array([4, 4, 4]) == 4)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I would have thought that numpy would propagate this error through, but it doesn't. For some reason it decides to evaluate the entire expression as False. It might be worth bringing this up on the numpy issue tracker.

As for solving your problem... is there any way you can use lists rather than arrays within your object array? I can't think of another way to get around it.

Edit: I submitted an issue at https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5016

Edit2: According to numpy developers, the current version of numpy raises a warning in this situation, and a future version will raise a ValueError when the elementwise comparison fails.

Comment: I think I need those to be arrays rather than lists.  For now I'll just use `[i for i,val in enumerate(foo) if val is 4]`.

Comment: From the numpy issue: it looks like the current behavior is deprecated and will lead to a ValueError in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow the nested `np.array` disturb the element-wise condition `== 4`. Nesting normal lists works just fine:

```py
import numpy as np
foo = np.array([[0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 3], [4, 4], 4], dtype=object)
np.where(foo == 4)
```

But I'm not sure why this makes the difference.